# include not found, how to fix with cmake?

Tags: linux, g++, cmake, include-path, cegui

there my CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8 )

set (CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

project( a.out )
find_package(OpenGL)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
pkg_search_module(CEGUI-GL REQUIRED  CEGUI-0-OPENGL)
pkg_search_module(CEGUI REQUIRED  CEGUI-0)


macro( config_project PROJNAME LIBNAME )
include_directories( ${${LIBNAME}_INCLUDE_DIR} )
target_link_libraries( ${PROJNAME} ${${LIBNAME}_LIBRARIES} )
endmacro()

add_definitions(-std=c++11)
add_executable(a.out src/ConsoleWindow.cc src/camera.cc src/main.cc)
config_project(a.out OPENGL)
config_project(a.out GLFW)
config_project(a.out CEGUI-GL)
config_project(a.out CEGUI)
```

so, there is `PkgConfig` for `CEGUI-0-OPENGL` and `CEGUI-0`. In `CEGUI-0.pc` there is:

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include/cegui-0
moduledir=${prefix}/lib/cegui-0.8
datafiles=${prefix}/share/cegui-0

Name: CEGUI-0
Description: The free GUI library for games and multi-media development.
Version: 0.8.2
Libs: -L${libdir} -lCEGUIBase-0
Cflags: -I${includedir} -I${includedir}/cegui
```

when I run `cmake .` everything is fine, but in one of my `.cc` I have :

```
#include <CEGUI/CEGUI.h>
```

and when I compil the file I got an error like no such file found... but `locate` return :

```
/usr/include/cegui-0/CEGUI/CEGUI.h
```

what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `include_directories( ${${LIBNAME}_INCLUDE_DIRS} )`?

Comment: @Fraser maybe, maybe not... actualy I have no idea... I added the `S` to my `include_directories( ${${LIBNAME}_INCLUDE_DIR}` (the one in the macro) there was no difference

Comment: Use [message](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:message) command to verify that all include dirs have value that you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some months later...

I think I solved this problem, I changed the line

```
include_directories( ${${LIBNAME}_INCLUDE_DIR} )
```

by

```
include_directories( ${${LIBNAME}_INCLUDEDIR} )
```

after noticing how `includedir` is typed in  `CEGUI-0.pc` ...

```
includedir=${prefix}/include/cegui-0
```

I don't get the "no file found error" for `#include <CEGUI/CEGUI.h>` anymore. I will try to do a hell-o world with CEGUI in my program next days. If you have any comment plz do.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and did not find a *clean* solution. I solved like this:

```
include_directories(${CEGUI_INCLUDE_DIR}/../)
```

which is probably not the best solution, but enough for me...